# Angular directive remove itself

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a gallery of images which each pull in related data. I've made a directive to lazy load the images once they are in view. It works well, but each of the directives continues watching for the scroll event, with around 200 of them, it's a lot of events being fired unnecessarily. Is there a way to remove the directive, or disable it?

```
app.directive('lazyLoadGallery', function(resourceService, $rootScope){
    return{
       link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
         var isLoaded = false;
         $('.issue-gallery').on('scroll', function(){
             console.log($rootScope.number);
             if((attrs.lazyLoadGallery/10) % 1 === 0 && !isLoaded) {
               if($(element).visible()){
                 isLoaded = true;
                 resourceService.issueListPages.list({number:$rootScope.number}).$promise.then(function(data){
                    $rootScope.issueList = $rootScope.issueList.concat(data.results);
                     $rootScope.number ++;
                     $(element).removeAttr('lazy-load-gallery');
                    });
               };
             }else{
                 $(element).removeAttr('lazy-load-gallery');
             }
         })

       }
    }
});
```

my attempt was to remove the attribute from the DOM. Even though it is removed the directive still is watching for scroll events and working as if it wasn't removed.

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Comment: Show the html structure. The scroll handler should be initialized once at higher level probably. Not clear how this works without seeing structure

Comment: don't use $rootScope and run `scope.$destroy()` after you removeAttr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to $destroy listeners on the parent object without eliminating it's event for all directives. I came up with a name spaced event which cleans up listeners.

```
app.directive('lazyLoadGallery', function(resourceService, $rootScope, $compile){
return{
   controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        var isLoaded = false;
        angular.element('.issue-gallery').on('scroll.'+ $scope.$id, function () {
            if (($attrs.lazyLoadGallery / 10) % 1 === 0 && !isLoaded) {
                if ($($element).visible()) {
                    isLoaded = true;
                    resourceService.issueListPages.list({number: $rootScope.number}).$promise.then(function (data) {
                        $rootScope.issueList = $rootScope.issueList.concat(data.results);
                        $rootScope.number++;
                        angular.element('.issue-gallery').off('scroll.'+ $scope.$id);
                    });
                }
                ;
            } else {
                angular.element('.issue-gallery').off('scroll.'+ $scope.$id);
            }
        })
   }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on) states that the return of $on function is

> Returns function()    Returns a deregistration function for this
>   listener.

So in your case just assign it to a variable and call it when you don't need it anymore.

```
var deregister = $scope.$on('something', function() {
    if (success) {
        deregister();
    }

});
```